# How to clear div output when input field is empty?

Tags: javascript, dom

I have simple weight converter and I would like to clear the output when input field is empty.

I've tried to use reset, clear or empty method, but no one of them worked

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.input');


form.addEventListener('keyup', e => {

  e.preventDefault();

  const getValue = form.add.value.trim();

  const convert = weight => {


    document.querySelector('.pounds').innerText = "Pounds: " + Math.round(weight * 2.20462262);
  };

  if (getValue.length) {
    convert(getValue);
  }

});
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>Todo List</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Weight converter</h1>
    <form class="input">
      <input type="number" name="add">
    </form>
    <div class="pounds green "></div>
    <div class="ounces red "></div>
    <div class="grams blue "></div>

  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ternary is useful

Also `input` handles paste

note I only preventDefault on the submit

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.input');
const output = document.querySelector('.pounds');
const convert = weight => {
  return "Pounds: " + Math.round(weight * 2.20462262);
};

form.addEventListener('submit', e => { // handles enter in the field
  e.preventDefault();
});
form.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const getValue = form.add.value.trim();
  output.innerText = getValue.length ? convert(getValue) : "";
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Weight converter</h1>
  <form class="input">
    <input type="number" name="add" id="add">
  </form>
  <div class="pounds green "></div>
  <div class="ounces red "></div>
  <div class="grams blue "></div>

</div>
```

Full code

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.input');
const convert = weight => {
  return {
    "pounds": Math.round(weight * 2.20462262),
    "ounces": Math.round(weight * 35.274),
    "grams": weight * 1000
  }
};

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
})
form.addEventListener('input', () => {
  const getValue = form.add.value.trim();
  if (getValue.length) {
    const weights = convert(getValue);
    for (w in weights) {
      document.querySelector("." + w).innerText = weights[w]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Weight converter</h1>
  <form class="input">
    <input type="number" name="add" id="add">
  </form>
  <div class="pounds green "></div>
  <div class="ounces red "></div>
  <div class="grams blue "></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the innerText to '' like so :

```
if (getValue.length) {
    convert(getValue);
} else {
  document.querySelector('.pounds').innerText = '';
}
```

This should work